# Map object to mongoose model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I `POST` a user object to my backend and I would like to be able to save this user directly to my database using Mongoose.

However, if I assign a new model with an object, it overwrites the save method.

e.g.

```
var user = new User();
user = req.body.user //save no longer available
user.save(function(err){
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to overcome this as at the moment I am having to assign each field for the user to the model like so:

```
var user = new User();
user.email = req.body.user.email;
user.name = req.body.user.name;
...
```

Comment: You can pass an object req.user to an Model, but it's a bad practice.
var user = new User(req.body.user);

Comment: well I am validating but I've not included that in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reassigning the variable `user` with the `req.body.user` value so the new model you originally assigned is discarded.

```
var foo = 'first'; // declares foo and assigns 'first' to it
foo = 'second'; // reassigns foo with value 'second'

var user = new User(); // declares user and assigns a new User model instance
user = req.body.user // reassigns user with value from req.body.user
```

You can pass the value to the User model constructor and this would achieve your desired result:

```
var user = new User(req.body.user); // declares user and assigns a new User model with req.body.user as the initial value
user.save(function(err){
  ...
});
```